# How to Work with a Optical Fiber Ribbon

Tags: ribbon-cable, optical-fibre, optical

I got a piece of fiber optical cable that is in the form of a "ribbon cable" (see pictures). I have seen tools and procedures for making connections on a single strand of optical fiber. I would like to know how to work "ribbon" type of optical fiber cables and what tools I would need.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @thephoton maybe you'd have an idea?

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I would assume you would split the wires back and connect ST connectors on them like normal single-strand cabling. Do you have the polishing/connector tools to work with the cable otherwise?

Comment: @thephoton I want to launch light through a slit into a monochromator. These fibers are already aligned. So it comes handy. But the fiber ends need to cleaved in unison. These fibers come from a construction site. So there must be some quite standard tool and procedure for working it.

Comment: You will need a cleaving tool and probably a polishing tool. These tools must exist somewhere, but looking on the sites I know that have fiber termination equipment, I don't see they carry these tools for ribbon fiber. You might be best off finding a local vendor who does fiber terminations and ask them to cleave and polish this fiber for you.